# how to access module variables in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby so I apologize for the noob question and thanks for the help. in ruby lets say I have a module like this:

```
module foo 
 a = 1
 b = 2
end
```

else in the code I have an object bar with a variable foo_id attached  to it.

is there an easy way to get 'a' or 'b' from the foo_id off the object bar? for example, doing something like this:

```
foo.get(bar.foo_id) #--> returning 'a'
```

The only idea that really comes to mind for me is making a get method in the module, is there a smarter ruby way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple hash:

```
module Foo
  IDS = {1 => 'a', 2 => 'b'}
end
```

And then access it:

```
Foo::IDS[bar.foo_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do the trick

```
module Foo
  IDS = {1 => 'a', 2 => 'b'}
end

puts Foo::IDS[1] #=> a
```